# Show a Result for Pressure Using Navier-Stokes Equation

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics

> By taking the divergence of the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation with a zero body force, $\underline{X} = \underline{0}$, show that the pressure satises
>   $$\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial x_i \partial x_i} = -\rho\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$$

In my notes I have this for an incompressible flow:
$$\begin{align}
\underline{\nabla}\cdot\underline{u} &= 0\tag1\\
\frac{\partial\underline{u}}{\partial t} + (\underline{u}\cdot\underline{\nabla})\underline{u} &= -\frac{1}{\rho}\underline{\nabla}p + \underline{X} + \nu\nabla^2\underline{u}\tag2\\
&= -\frac{1}{\rho}\underline{\nabla}p + \nu\nabla^2\underline{u}\quad\text{with $\underline{X} = \underline{0}$}\end{align}$$

I'm juse not sure how to take the divergence of all this to get the final result?

Answer (score 1):

For an incompressible fluid it is clear that $\dot\rho=0$. Then via the continuity equation we find 
$$
\nabla\cdot u = 0 .
$$
We can now take the divergence of the Navier-Stokes equation and get
$$
-\nabla^2 P = \rho\nabla_j(u_i\nabla_i u_j).
$$
The easiest way to solve this constraint is to convert the NS equation into an equation for the vorticity
$\omega=\nabla\times u$. Thus 
$$
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t} 
 + u\cdot\nabla {\omega} = \eta {\nabla}^2 {\omega}
  + \omega\cdot\nabla {u},
$$
where $\eta=\eta/\rho$ is the kinetic viscosity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But you say that you take the divergence of the NS equ. and that is what I am not sure how to do in tensor form @Kevin

Comment: @Michael For a rank-2 tensor which corresponds to a matrix, say $A$, its divergence is just the vector $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, where $b_j$ is the divergence of the $j$th-column or row vector of $A$, depending on the convention.

Answer (score 0):

To show how this elliptic equation for the pressure emerges from the traditional momentum equation, take the divergence

$$\partial_t \operatorname{div}u + \operatorname{div}(u\cdot \nabla u)+\operatorname{div}\nabla p = \Delta(\operatorname{div}u) + \operatorname{div}f$$

and use that $u$ has vanishing divergence
$$-\Delta p = \operatorname{div}(u\cdot \nabla u)-\operatorname{div}f$$

You can rewrite this using the "divergence of a dyad rule"
$$\operatorname{div}(u\otimes u) = u\underbrace{\operatorname{div}u}_{=0}  + u\cdot \nabla u$$

which yields
$$-\Delta p = \operatorname{div}\operatorname{div}(u\otimes u) -\operatorname{div}f$$

In case you require this in Einstein index notation with implicit double-index summations, you can write
$$[(u\cdot \nabla)u]_j \equiv u_i \partial_i u_j.$$

This quantity has 1 free index (j), and is therefore a 1-tensor (or vector). Now we apply the divergence to it and get
$$\partial_j u_i \partial_i u_j$$

Which is exactly what you have in the first line of your question.